# A verb for "deficiency"?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

There are several verbs in English meaning "cause" such as "give rise to", "bring about", "generate", ... .

But each of such verbs seems to be more idiomatic for particular things. For example, when we talk about arguments or disputes in sentences such as the below, "give rise to" seems more idiomatic than some other verbs with similar meaning.

> decisions which give rise to arguments.

Now, my question is which of the above verbs, or similar verbs, is the most idiomatic for "deficiency" in sentences such as the below:

> That feature ------- a deficiency for our system.

Comment: Does the feature cause or just reveal the deficiency?

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone It causes the deficiency. So a verb is wanted meaning the same. Or, isn't "cause" itself the most idiomatic verb?

Comment: The obvious course of action would be to look at Google Ngrams, and raw Google data, for 'gave rise to a deficiency' / 'produced ...' / 'caused ...' / 'brought about ...' / .... That would produce reasonable research to show.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "cause" seems to be the most popular on Ngram. But would you, as a native English speaker, do the same?

Comment: I don't think a feature can cause a deficiency, but it might reveal, exploit, magnify, capitalize on, or take advantage of an existing deficiency.

Comment: I can't see me ever using "a deficiency for our system" (no hits on Google either), so looking for a strong collocate is pointless. I've no problem with "brought about / gave rise to / caused a deficiency" per se.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It doesn't need to be a system and a feature.

Comment: @Davo It doesn't need to be a feature.

Comment: Which verb you'd use depends on how the deficiency arises in light of the feature. Eg the feature poking a metaphoric hole in the system vs the feature depriving the system of scarce resources, etc. The verb depends more on the interaction between feature and system than on the mere existence and reference to them.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: Did you try a thesaurus? 'leads to' works

Answer (score 0):

That feature ***results in*** a deficiency ***to*** our system.

From:

en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/result

*A thing that is caused or produced by something else.*

Answer (score 0):

- Produce
- Effect
- Precipitate
- Induce
- Trigger

Comment: OP asked for an ordering in idiomaticity, not just a list of suggested synonyms.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth All the words suggested fill the blank (in the OP's sentence) quite well.  "Produce a deficiency", "trigger a deficiency" etc. Or produced a deficiency if a single feature is discussed.

Comment: OP asked for an ordering in idiomaticity, not just a list of suggested synonyms. You don't offer any evidence suggesting that say 'precipitate' is the most idiomatic choice.

Answer (score -2):

**add up to**:to have a particular result or effect: ([Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/add-up-to-sth))

*That feature added up to a deficiency for our system.*

**add up to:** to signify; indicate:([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/add--up--to))

Comment: How does a single thing add up to something?

Comment: @Davo: **The evidence adds up to a case of murder**. Is this sentence okay?